# Why won't draft listings appear for non-admins?

Tags: wp-query, post-status, draft

I have a draft post with the author set to 5. User #5 is trying to view that draft on the front end using a WP_Query with the  following arguments:

```
array {
  ["name"]=> "example-52f00a8ba19f4"
  ["post_status"]=> array {
    [0]=> "draft"
    [1]=> "private"
  }
  ["post_type"]=> "customlisting"
  ["posts_per_page"]=> 1
  ["author"]=> 5
}
```

The user trying to view this is user #5. They are trying to view their own draft post, so that they can publish it... (on the front end)

The SQL query that is available in `$wp_query->request` **does in fact return the listing** ([screenshot from HeidiSQL](http://radleygh.com/images/heidisql_2014-035-12-16-08-74.png)). But it does not appear in `$wp_query->posts`, and it seems WP_Query is removing it after the actual SQL query.

How can I prevent WP_Query from removing this? I don't know where to look. I don't know why it's happening either :/

**Update:** It seems the query only fails if searching by post name. It works by post ID (post__in, rather).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed processing in `WP_Query` which might [prevent posts from displaying](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2972) if they are not simply public.

Since there are several conditions there it is a little hard to guess why it fails in your specific case. It might be issue with how permissions are setup or some edge case (which querying for non-public posts is *full* of).

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a particular condition where you search by post name (slug). It does work if I specify the ID, and I may need to change the entire draft mode of this plugin if I can't find a way around that.

Comment: To circumvent the issue in my last comment, I used `$wpdb` to look up the ID of the post by the slug, then did a query for the post ID directly.